# undefined method `cache_getter' for Typhoeus::Hydra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, typhoeus, hydra

I don't know why I get this error. Both methods are corrects.

```
hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.new

             hydra.cache_getter do |request|
                Rails.cache.read(request.cache_key) rescue nil
             end
             hydra.cache_setter do |request|
               Rails.cache.write(request.cache_key,request.response, expires_in: request.cache_timeout)
             end
```

ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]

Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because those methods do not exist on an instance of Typhoeus::Hydra. You can find the full list of available methods at http://rubydoc.info/gems/typhoeus/0.5.0/frames

**Update**

Those methods were removed between versions [0.4.2 and 0.5.0](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/compare/v0.4.2...v0.5.0) via [this commit](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/commit/c4f9a6b5e91a17ef9c3f2f4a9a95b7d9fee3f37e#lib/typhoeus/hydra.rb)

Comment: Ok, thanks, So there are no more cache system in Typhoeus now?

Comment: Good question, I haven't done anything with caching in Typhoeus. I'd recommend contacting the author and see what's up. Unfortunately that commit message sucks :(

Comment: typhoeus has caching facilities build in. when i got it correctly, they just changed the interface for the getter and setter methods and wrap it in a class. see: https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#caching